# Which one is better? LazyDataModel or LiveScroll

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am using LazyDataModel to display the data table records, pagination, filter, sorting purpose. The records can be max 2500 around. I display 10 Records per page, so customer has to visit 250 pages if they don't know the search term. Now customer don't want to visit all the pages rather they want the implementation where they can do all the stuff being on the same page. 
The other option which comes in mind is live scroll but I tried to work on PoC and come to know that LazyDataModel and Live Scroll doesn't work together. So I created a demo page independent of LazyDataModel using Live Scroll. I really like live scrolling when it comes to filter the records as it is much faster. The only thing is drill down till the end.

I have following questions:

1. How live scroll works internally?
2. Does Live Scroll load the data all together and fetch it from heap or cache? (i.e. scrollRows="20")
3. If Live Scroll can do better then why LazyDataModel?
4. Don't you think that pagination is all about old days?

Comment: Try to ask one question per question and use a less subjective title. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum or so.

Comment: @BalusC Any idea about how live scroll loads records?